# Is it possible to shorten the amount of time before an Ad Hoc build provisioning profile expires?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, provisioning, adhoc

I've got a client who has a very late invoice and has promised to mail me a check, but they need a new Ad Hoc build of the app because the provisioning profile has expired. I'd like to do a new build but set a shorter expiration limit for the Ad Hoc provisioning profile or be able to revoke the profile if they don't pay.

Is it possible to get the Ad Hoc provisioning profile to expire sooner than the 90 day default, or alternatively, does revoking the provisioning profile disable the Ad Hoc build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about inserting a call to your server as a second authentication...have a file with "yes", and if it stays "yes" the app will run the life of the provisioning profile. If you change it to "no" (or anything non-'yes') due to non-payment, push some modal view without a dismiss ability. (BUT, I would consider flipping the yes/no depending on the other features of the app...for instance, if they went to airplane mode, so couldn't actually get to the yes, it'd display the block, so you might want to make it only display the block if it CAN get 'no'...so they'd be able to defeat it if they went to airplane, but maybe that would disable other parts of the app...so it'd be a call for you to make based on the function of the app.

(and then remove this function on subsequent builds post-payment)

Comment: Very good! I'd do it slightly different, though: If the server returns yes, proceed loading the app. If the server cannot be reached, have a grace period counter decrease one step. If the counter drops to zero (after maybe five launches without contact to the server) or if the server returns "stick it up your a..", display a warning that they should pay immediately. Oh, and don't forget to reset the grace counter the next time the server returns "yes"...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. But you could add code to your app to check a website each time it's launch or come from background which will tell it to continue or not.

Answer (score 0):

I use his code. This will not work if the user change the date of its device but if he doesn't, that does the trick (note that I use french date style, you may have to change that) :

```
/***** Time bombing code to get a demo that only works for a certain period of time *****/
-(BOOL) isDateDeprecated {
    return NO;
    BOOL deprecated = NO;
    // Get today date
   // NSDate* today = [NSDate date];

    // Get limit date date
    NSDateFormatter* frDateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [frDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:yyyy"];
    NSLocale *frLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"] autorelease];
    [frDateFormatter setLocale:frLocale];

    NSString* LIMIT_DATE_STRING = @"26:06:2011";
    NSDate* limitDate = [frDateFormatter dateFromString:LIMIT_DATE_STRING];
    NSLog (@"Limit value %f %@", [limitDate timeIntervalSinceNow], limitDate);
    if ([limitDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0) {
        deprecated = YES;
    }
    return deprecated;
}

-(void) displayNoLaunchingScreen {
    NoLaunchingScreen* noLaunchingViewController = [[[NoLaunchingScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"NoLaunchingScreen" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [window addSubview:noLaunchingViewController.view];
}
```

You just need to check isDateDepcrated when you application starts or restarts and if it is true, you launch displayNoLaunchingScreen.